# String initialization with double quotes

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm doing some tutorial, and had this line

```
const std::string spaces(greeting.size(), " ");
```

However that didn't work until i changed double quotes to single quotes like

```
const std::string spaces(greeting.size(), ' ');
```

What is the point about quotes in string initialization? I've tried to check http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/, but didn't find something that would explain this to me

Comment: [This reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string), explains it well enough for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are character literals and string literals in C++.

For example a character enclosed in single quotes like 'A' denotes a character literal and represents one character and has type `char`.

If you will enclose symbol A in double quotes like `"A"` then you get a string literal that has type `cont char[2]` and has internal representation like

```
{ 'A', '\0' }
```

that is it consists from two characters including the terminating zero.

You can see the difference running this simple porgram

```
#includde <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "sizeof( 'A' ) = " << sizeof( 'A' ) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "sizeof( \"A\" ) = " << sizeof( "A" ) << std::endl;
}
```

Class std::basic_string (or std::string) has the following constructor

```
basic_string(size_type n, charT c, const Allocator& a = Allocator());
```

and in this declaration

```
const std::string spaces(greeting.size(), ' ');
```

this constructor is used. It initializes the string with the greeting.size() number of space character.

Answer (score 2):

Double-quoted `" "` is string literal in C++ (represented by `const char [N]`), while single-quoted `' '` is a character literal (`char`), so you were calling `(std::size_t, const char [N])` constructor.

It doesn't exist, so you get a compilation error.

You need to change it to one of the available constructors like:

```
string (size_t n, char c);
string (const char* s);
```

(which you already did by changing second parameter to `' '`)

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're using this constructor: `string (size_t n, char c)` (no. 6 in the reference you linked), which fills the newly constructed string with `n` chars `c`. If you use double quotes you create a string literal, single quotes mean chars.